# Turning Web App to Mobile App... PhoneGap?

Tags: php, android, html, mobile, cordova

I want to delve in to mobile applications, specifically Android apps (I am an Android fanboy). My web application is a content based site; built with PHP/MySQL and served with a lot of HTML5, CSS3 and JQuery.

What would be the best starting point and direction to take to begin development of a mobile application? I've seen a couple of videos on PhoneGap and it seems very interesting with its standards-based cross-platform approach. Is that a good way to go?

My basic intend is to have an application that can load content from my site (served to the app probably as JSON or XML) which the application can render in native UI (or make use of local storage etc. that a simple web content frame won't do). I guess it would be a glorified mobile site, but I want it to me slightly more with the ability to save and render content for if internet is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PhoneGap** does a nice job of bridging native APIs so they are available to your JavaScript.  What you really need to consider though is the look, feel, and performance of the HTML/CSS/JavaScript you run on top of **PhoneGap**.

I have recently started building an app with **JQueryMobile**.  The look and feel is really nice, and I was able to build something very rapidly.  However, ***page transitions are very blinky/choppy*** to the point where I don't think its acceptable.  This is really a problem with Android's browser performance and not JQuery Moble.

**Sencha Touch** seems to have animations and transitions that are a bit smoother, but it has a steeper learning curve.

Another option is to create an application which is a **hybrid**, containing some **PhoneGap** based `Activities` and some purely native `Activities`.

Since you are already familiar with web development, I would suggest doing a quick sprint with **PhoneGap** and **Sencha Touch**.  If it looks promising, stick with it.  If it doesn't, abandon it for a native app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use native UI & controls, then Phonegap will not help you. It essentially wraps HTML/CSS/JS in an app & provide JS API's for native device features. It does not help you create native UI & controls.

You can directly code in native Java or use [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) if you want to code in JS and build portable apps with native UI.

Comment: I've updated that part of my question. I guess I am okay with the way Phonegap works as far as allowing access to OS APIs on mobile platforms. I don't mind being able to reuse some of the code I have already written, especially the stylesheets in a mobile app. Titanium looks good too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to be targeting Android, then I would suggest avaioding PhoneGap or other cross platform SDK's.  If you're comfortable with Java or are willing to learn, go with the Android SDK tools and Eclipse.

I have found that working with JSON is extremely simple on Android, and dealing with xml is not that much harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay away from coding in Java, you could simply use what you have already as an HTML5 app, and create a new mobile CSS to reflow the look and layout of your app. That way, you can still use all the HTML and javascript you are currently using, and get your info from the same server...

In my experience though, Android web app are very slow... unfortunately (and hopefully Chrome will fix this) android browser is very bad with javascript... very slow.